# I got some error message when I upload file to softlayer object storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I used this https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-php in my
laravel project.

I'll call

```
$newObject = $objectStorage->with('mycontainer/path/test.png')
                        ->setLocalFile('C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/Great-Impression.jpg')
                        ->setMeta('description', 'first test file')
                        ->create();
```

after that I got some message error

```
ObjectStorage_Exception_Http_RequestTimeout in D:\Works\mytest\vendor\softlayer\objectstorage\lib\ObjectStorage.php line 552:
```

Failed to create ObjectStorage Object.

but when I removed `->setLocalFile('C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/Great-Impression.jpg')` it's work fine.

Please advise how to fix this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue, his code it's fine, anyway I tried with this:

```
<?php
require_once ('lib/ObjectStorage/Util.php');

/**
 * Declare Object Storage parameters
 */
$host = 'https://mil01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/';
// Declare your username and password for Object Storage connection
$username = 'set me';
$password = 'set me';
$options = array('adapter' => ObjectStorage_Http_Client::SOCKET, 'timeout' => 10);

/**
 * Create Object Storage Connection
 */
$objectStorage = new ObjectStorage($host, $username, $password, $options);

/**
 * Upload file
 */
$newObject = $objectStorage->with('mycontainer/path/test.png')
                        ->setLocalFile('C:/Users/Ruber Cuellar/Pictures/test.jpg')
                        ->setMeta('description', 'first test file')
                        ->create();
// Print Result     
print($newObject);
```

Could you provide more information about this issue?

- the cluster (datacenter) that you tried?
- are you able to upload this file to other cluster (other datacenter)?
- did you tried with another image?

Comment: the cluster (datacenter) that you tried? - I used Singapore 1

are you able to upload this file to other cluster (other datacenter)?
- I changed cluster to Milan 1 like you it can't upload.

did you tried with another image?
- Yes, I couldn't upload too.

Comment: Something weird, I tried with Singapore and I had success too. Do you have this path **mycontainer/path** created in your object storage?, are you able to make another request like create or get containers?

Comment: I don't sure why I couldn't upload yesterday. But today I test again it's work!. Thank you.

Comment: Something weird, but it's great that it works now. If you continue facing this issue in the future, feel free to ask in this thread for further investigation